# Ajax response not appears inside success function - jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying simple login form with username, password fields in jquery mobile. Username and password should validate from ajax page. In my system i am able to get response perfectly. When convert my code to .apk uging phonegap, my mobile unable to receive response from ajax page. Any code inside success function is not working, Directly it goes to error function. What am i doing wrong?

```
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#login', function(){
        $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
        if($('#username').val().length > 0 && $('#password').val().length > 0){
            $.ajax({
                url : 'liveurl/check.php',
                data: {action : 'login', formData : $('#check-user').serialize()}, 
                type: 'post',
                beforeSend: function() {
                     $.mobile.loading(true);                 },
                complete: function() {
                     $.mobile.loading(false); 
                },
                success: function (result) {
                   if(result.status == "success"){  
                        resultObject.formSubmitionResult = result.uname;
                        localStorage["login_details"] = window.JSON.stringify(result);
                        $.mobile.changePage("#second");
                }else{
                        $.mobile.changePage("#login");
                        alert("incorrect login");           
                }
                    },
                    error: function (request,error) {
                        alert(error);    
                    }
                });                   
        } else {
            alert('Fill all nececery fields');
        }           
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: are you using https on the liveurl? can you explain what do you mean by "In my system i am able to get response perfectly."?

Comment: yes i am using http only. I guess phonegap is unable to respond for http url.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by "In my system i am able to get response perfectly."?

Comment: My code works perfectly on my desktop. when convert it to .apk and use in mobile(phonegap) it is not working. No response nothing.

Comment: then it's probably a whitelist problem, you have to install the whitelist plugin and configure it to allow external connections. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me the file structure for config.xml, index.html. it will be helpful to convert as proper .apk file

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. Your APK is not running on your server. That means, that your url is wrong it needs to be something like:

> url: "http://www.your_server.com/liveurl/check.php"

2. You have to whitelisten every external url, please read the docs for that:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For example only i noted as 'liveurl/check.php'. Url format is given as you said. Now i need to concentrate on whitelist only.